# bottom:0 having issues in iphone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

Hey guys i have the following social media , icons on my site:

```
<ul class="nav-social-media">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>    
 </ul>
```

I have the following CSS applied:

```
.nav-social-media {
    /*padding-left: 2em;*/
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
} 

.nav-social-media  > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.62em; 
}

.nav-social-media  > li > a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

as you can see the `bottom:0` , so this is how the social media icons look on mobile:

[image]

but in iphone6 this causes the following problem:

[image: iphone 6 issue]

See how the iphone bottom bar covers the social icons, how can this be overcome ? is there a native iphone hack that can be used , instead of a hack that will effect devices of similar resolutions ?

P.S. for now i have increased the value of `bottom` to overcome this.

Comment: can you use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`?

Comment: the container of the social icons is already position:fixed .

Comment: I meant to `.nav-social-media`

Comment: Oic , let me try that :)

Comment: Anyone find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known issue by design with Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832)

> This is completely intentional. It took quite a bit of work on our part to achieve this effect. :)
>
> The base problem is this: the visible area changes dynamically as you scroll. If we update the CSS viewport height accordingly, we need to update the layout during the scroll. Not only that looks like shit, but doing that at 60 FPS is practically impossible in most pages (60 FPS is the baseline framerate on iOS).
>
> It is hard to show you the “looks like shit” part, but imagine as you scroll, the contents moves and what you want on screen is continuously shifting.
>
> Dynamically updating the height was not working, we had a few choices: drop viewport units on iOS, match the document size like before iOS 8, use the small view size, use the large view size.
>
> From the data we had, using the larger view size was the best compromise. Most website using viewport units were looking great most of the time.

**Reference blogs with perhaps some workarounds**

- https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html
- https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/mobile-safari-why/

Comment: thanks .. will looking this and accept if fits my needs

Comment: So they've decided to give you no option of determining if the bar is open and how big it is? Where's the best hack answer?